# Движение объекта при клике на форму

Tags: delphi

Есть объект(картинка) и определённое пространство(форма), объект может находиться в любой точке этого пространства. При клике на форму(пространство) объект должен с определённой скоростью "приползти" в то место, куда кликнули мышкой.
Помогите это организовать.

Comment: а что собственно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

таймер на форму, по клику таймер запускается, в обработке события OnTimer меняете координаты объекта на фиксированный шаг, пока он не доползёт до нужной точки. Скорость можно задать шагом или интервалом таймера